# React Native wrapper for Connectivity Manager

Tags: react-native, networking, automation, android-wifi

Im looking for the library in RN community that can help me manage my active wifi connection.  I would like to connect/disconnect to certain wifi networks.

The equivalent class in Java is:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager

Answer (score 0):

`NetInfo` may solve your problem.
Here is an example
Find more here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo

```
import {NetInfo} from 'react-native';

NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then((connectionInfo) => {
  console.log(
    'Initial, type: ' +
      connectionInfo.type +
      ', effectiveType: ' +
      connectionInfo.effectiveType,
  );
});
function handleFirstConnectivityChange(connectionInfo) {
  console.log(
    'First change, type: ' +
      connectionInfo.type +
      ', effectiveType: ' +
      connectionInfo.effectiveType,
  );
  NetInfo.removeEventListener(
    'connectionChange',
    handleFirstConnectivityChange,
  );
}
NetInfo.addEventListener('connectionChange', handleFirstConnectivityChange);
```